# Adding Click Event listener to Pushpin

Tags: android, bing-maps

I'm having problem with the `EntityClickedListener` in Bing Maps. I coded it following the example given:

```
map.setEntityClickedListener(new EntityClickedListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onAvailableChecked(String layerName, int entityId)
   {
      HashMap<String, Object> metadata = map.getLayerManager.GetMetadataByID(layerName, entityId);
      Toast.makeText(Activity.this, metadata.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
           .show();
   }
});
```

However, clicking on the the `Pushpin` does nothing. I created a Toast message to see exactly what's in the metadata but nothing happens. Looking through the path the application, I can tell that Bing uses a data service to retrieve its information:

```
bsds.FindByAreaCompleted = new Handler(){
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
     if(msg.obj != null){
        Record[] records = (Record[])msg.obj;
        EntityLayer el = (EntityLayer)bingMapsView.getLayerManager().getLayerByName(Constants.DataLayers.Search);
        double maxLat = -90, minLat = 90, maxLon = -180, minLon = 180;

        for(Record r : records){
            Pushpin p = new Pushpin(r.Location);
            p.Title = r.DisplayName;
            HashMap<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            metadata.put("record", r);
            el.add(p, metadata);
        }

     bingMapsView.setMapView(new LocationRect(maxLat, maxLon, minLat, minLon));

     el.updateLayer();
     }
};
```

I've also edited the JavaScript file to remove some checking that may have prevented the `Listener` from working:

```
this.ShowInfobox = function(entity){
        window.BingMapsInterlop.entityClicked(entity.layerName, entityId);
    };

var Layer = function(name, map, dataLayer)
{
    this.Name = name;

    var entities = new MM.EntityCollection(),
    _map = map;

    this.AddEntities = function(data)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            var i = data.length - 1;
            if (i >= 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    data[i].Entity.entityId = data[i].EntityId;
                    data[i].Entity.layerName = name;

                    // Commented out
                    // if(data[i].title != null && data[i].title != undefined && data[i].title != '')
                    // {
                        data[i].Entity.title = data[i].title;

                        MM.Events.addHandler(data[i].Entity, 'click', function(e)
                        {
                            BingMapsAndroid.ShowInfobox(e.target);
                        });
                    // }
                    entities.push(data[i].Entity);
                }
                while (i--)
            }
        }
    };
    // fluff
};
```

Have I edited the JavaScript file correctly? I don't know JavaScript myself and I've been following [this guide](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/discussions/263960). The `Pushpin` is being added and I'm seeing on my `BingMapsView`, but the `OnClick` method doesn't execute. Is there something I'm missing?

The path that Bing takes to create Listeners and events for `Pushpin` click events is almost a labyrinth in my opinion. There has to be a simpler way to do this that I'm missing. Can anyone give any advice?

Comment: may be its a problem of view overlay

Comment: Does anybody have working code of the `EntityClickListener` for Bing Maps? If you can just give me some code I can try to figure it out myself. I've been tearing my hair out over this for the past couple of weeks.

Comment: Hi @Yawus, did you try this link, http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/discussions/263960/

Comment: @Rahul I already linked that discussion in my question. I've been trying to edit the JavaScript file but I don't know enough of JavaScript to be sure I'm doing the right things.

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay I found my answer in case you were interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the answer! Edit the following methods in JavaScript file like so such that the script doesn't check for metadata that doesn't exist.

```
var Layer = function(name, map, dataLayer)
{
    this.Name = name;

    var entities = new MM.EntityCollection(),
    _map = map;

    this.AddEntities = function(data)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            var i = data.length - 1;
            if (i >= 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    data[i].Entity.entityId = data[i].EntityId;
                    data[i].Entity.layerName = name;

                    // Commented out
                    // if(data[i].title != null && data[i].title != undefined && data[i].title != '')
                    // {
                        data[i].Entity.title = data[i].title;

                        MM.Events.addHandler(data[i].Entity, 'click', function(e)
                        {
                            BingMapsAndroid.ShowInfobox(e.target);
                        });
                    // }
                    entities.push(data[i].Entity);
                }
                while (i--)
            }
        }
    };
    // fluff
};
```

Then, change the `ShowInfoBox` method in the JavaScript file to

```
this.ShowInfobox = function (entity) {
        window.BingMapsInterlop.entityClicked(entity.layerName, entity.entityId);
    };
```

This code funnels straight to the click listener you code in your `Activity` instead of messing around with it in the JavaScript. The difference from the JavaScript I edited earlier is that the parameter for the `entityClicked` method should actually be `entity.entityId` not `entityId`.